# Can't install data.table package on MacOS 10.12+ using clang

Tags: r, macos, installation, data.table, clang

Thanks for clicking in. I've been trying to solve this for hours but nothing seem to work.

My operating system: MacOS sierra OS version: 10.12.3
 R version: 3.3.3

I've followed the data.table download instruction here: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation
But it's still not working

the error message is as below:

```
*> install.packages("data.table", type = "source",
+                  repos = "http://Rdatatable.github.io/data.table")
嘗試 URL 'http://Rdatatable.github.io/data.table/src/contrib/data.table_1.10.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 2843331 bytes (2.7 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.7 MB

* installing *source* package ‘data.table’ ...
** libs
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c assign.c -o assign.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c between.c -o between.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c bmerge.c -o bmerge.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c chmatch.c -o chmatch.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c dogroups.c -o dogroups.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c fastmean.c -o fastmean.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c fcast.c -o fcast.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c fmelt.c -o fmelt.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c forder.c -o forder.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c frank.c -o frank.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c fread.c -o fread.o
fread.c:64:19: warning: unused variable 'TypeName' [-Wunused-const-variable]
static const char TypeName[NUMTYPE][10] = {"LGL","INT","INT64","REAL","STR","NULL"};  // for messages and errors
                  ^
1 warning generated.
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c fsort.c -o fsort.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c fwrite.c -o fwrite.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c gsumm.c -o gsumm.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c ijoin.c -o ijoin.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c init.c -o init.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c inrange.c -o inrange.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c openmp-utils.c -o openmp-utils.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c quickselect.c -o quickselect.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c rbindlist.c -o rbindlist.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c reorder.c -o reorder.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c shift.c -o shift.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c subset.c -o subset.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c transpose.c -o transpose.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c uniqlist.c -o uniqlist.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c vecseq.c -o vecseq.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c wrappers.c -o wrappers.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -o data.table.so assign.o between.o bmerge.o chmatch.o dogroups.o fastmean.o fcast.o fmelt.o forder.o frank.o fread.o fsort.o fwrite.o gsumm.o ijoin.o init.o inrange.o openmp-utils.o quickselect.o rbindlist.o reorder.o shift.o subset.o transpose.o uniqlist.o vecseq.o wrappers.o -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
mv data.table.so datatable.so
if [ "" != "Windows_NT" ] && [ `uname -s` = 'Darwin' ]; then install_name_tool -id datatable.so datatable.so; fi
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/data.table/libs
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  無法載入共享物件 '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/data.table/libs/datatable.so' ：
 dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/data.table/libs/datatable.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libomp.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/data.table/libs/datatable.so
  Reason: image not found
錯誤: loading failed
停止執行
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/data.table’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘data.table’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/n3/4f7rv1dj4ys_1z2hwh95z79h0000gn/T/RtmplcaPNQ/downloaded_packages’*
```

Comment: try using the `devtools` package: `devtools::install_github("Rdatatable/data.table")`

Comment: thanks @yeedle , but that did't work either = (

Comment: `devtools` worked for me after `install.packages()` failed

Answer (score 2):

The first is a warning about a no longer used variable as of a few days ago since you are installing the latest development version (which is fine) :

```
fread.c:64:19: warning: unused variable 'TypeName' [-Wunused-const-variable]
static const char TypeName[NUMTYPE][10]
```

That's a correct warning and I'll remove that variable.

The second is the error :

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  無法載入共享物件 '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/data.table/libs/datatable.so' ：
 dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/data.table/libs/datatable.so, 6):
Library not loaded: @rpath/libomp.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/data.table/libs/datatable.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Other people are finding that too on MacOS and seem to be having some success with the solutions [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2055) using gcc instead of clang. The problems appears to be clang on MacOS, not data.table. No problems have been reported on Linux or Windows.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked after changing to gcc, thanks again.

Comment: @StefanTien Great!  Please update our [Installation page](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) as you see fit to help others. (It's a wiki so you can edit it.)

Comment: If you end up here and find this a not very helpful answer, then do also read https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/